# Get the last folder's ID from given file path string to act as the parent ID of a new folder being created

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, algorithm, linq

I have folder objects that are stored in a way that I can see which folder is in which other folder. These objects have `id`, `name` and `parentId`attributes. Each folder's `parentId` is the `id` of another folder. The root folder's parent Id is null.

I have a form which allows to create new folders. The form takes a `name` (string) and a `parent` (string) input. The name can be anything, but the parent must be in the format of existing folders: `"Documents|Books|Fiction"`, etc. If there are no folders existing already, to create the initial `Documents` folder, the parent can be empty.

I am struggling in finding the algorithm to ensure a new folder is mapped in the correct folder given the file path of parent. For example, if the folder structure looks like the following:

`Documents|Holidays`

`Documents|Books|Holidays`

`Documents|Jobs|Books|Holidays`

And lets say that I am creating a new folder with `name` `"My Day in Paris"` and `parent` `"Documents|Books|Holidays"` In the controller method for `CreateFolder`, before I save the new `Folder` object to the database, I need to give this `Folder` object the `ParentId` of the parent folder. In our case the parent is `Holidays` folder which has the path `"Documents|Books|Holidays"`.

For example,I could query the database (pseudocode):
`db.Folders.where(x => x.Name == "Holidays").Select(y => y.Id).single();` But this will not get me the right folder from the file path to set the correct ParentId.

How can I get the parent Id in this way? I tried searching around for ages and tried to work out an algorithm but no luck.

**Update with my own attempt. It reaches the correct value to return, but instead of returning this value, it continues back to the previously paused recursive cycles. How do I break with the output value without it going back?**

```
public int GetIdFromPath(string path)
        {
            int _parentId = 0;
            var folderStructure = GetFolderStructure();

            if (path != null)
            {
                _parentId = recursiveFunction(path, folderStructure);
                return _parentId;
            }

            return _parentId;
        }

        private int recursiveFunction(string path, List<Folder> folders)
        {
            var splitPath = path.Split('|');
            var _parentId = 0;
            foreach (var item in splitPath)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var folder in folders)
                    {
                        if (folder.Name == item)
                        {
                            splitPath = splitPath.Where(x => x != item).ToArray();
                            _parentId = folder.Id;

                            if (splitPath.Count() > 0)
                            {
                                var newPath = string.Join("|", splitPath);
                                recursiveFunction(newPath, folder.FolderBookmarks.OfType<Folder>().ToList());
                            }

                            return _parentId;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return _parentId;
                }
            }

            return _parentId;
        }

        public List<Folder> GetFolders()
        {
            var folders = db.Bookmarks.OfType<Folder>().ToList();
            return folders;
        }

        public List<Folder> GetFolderStructure()
        {
            var folders = GetFolders();

            foreach (var folder in folders)
            {
                var bookmarks = db.Bookmarks.Where(x => x.ParentId == folder.Id).ToList();
                folder.FolderBookmarks = bookmarks;
            }

            return folders;
        }
```

Comment: something like a tree view structure with `Parent` / `Children` properties ?

Comment: Hi Aybe, I see, but I am trying to complete this using parent_Id reference only. Thanks.

Comment: You need to write a recursive algorithm.  Probably better to use GetFiles() method and on get one directory at a time rather then getting all subfolders.  Code is very simple.  Have written many times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with the solution. The variable `folders` is a list of folder objects. (Note: Folders have many folders). The code below sets the parent ID as the folder ID of the folder name that matches the path name. The folders list then gets set to that folder's internal list of folders; this will allow to look within the folder. (Also note that we do not allow duplicate folder names in this context). Thanks Reza, your comment helped!

```
public int GetParentIdFromPath(string path)
    {
        int _parentId = 0;

        if (path != null)
        {
            var folders = GetFolderStructure();
            var splitPath = path.Split('|');

            foreach (var item in splitPath)
            {
                _parentId = folders.Where(x => x.Name == item).SingleOrDefault().Id;
                folders = folders.Where(x => x.Name == item).SingleOrDefault().FolderBookmarks.OfType<Folder>().ToList();
            }

            return _parentId;
        }

        return _parentId;
    }
```

Comment: Can anyone recommend how I can become more proficient and faster at coding algorithms? This took me a day to think and 5 hours to develop from the guidance received here. My friends were quicker at solving this than I was.

Answer (score 1):

You must find each parent step by step like this and also handle exceptions:

```
int? _parentId = null;
foreach (var item in path.Split('|'))
{
    var folder = db.Folders
                    .where(x => x.Name == item&&x.ParentId = _parentId)
                    .Select(y => y.Id)
                    .Single();
    _parentId = folder.Id;
}
return _parentId;
```

Comment: I was writing an aswer with a recursive aproximation, but I liked this

Comment: Thanks Reza, I understand, but this will not be suitable for folders that have the same name of existing folders. For example, if I have `"Documents|Holidays|Pictures"` and `"Documents|University|Pictures"` and file path for a new folder is `"Documents|University|Pictures"`, then the code will not get an id, since there are two `"Picture"` folders. The code throws an exception with this. I try to handle by making a list of the folders with the name, but not sure how to get the Id of the correct `"Pictures"` folder.

Comment: @naz786- you didn't understand the code, I trace the tree from top to bottom so every search executed in child of a parent, in your example when we want to search 'pictures' we search in it's parent child's('university' childs).